# notepad++ regex - remove brackets and separate values

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have list:

```
(1, 'Apple', '["5","8"]'),
...
(22, 'Mango', '["5","8"]'),
(23, 'Orange', '["5","8"]'),
(24, 'Banana', '["2","0"]'),
(25, 'Milk', '["2","0"]'),
...
(749, 'Bread', '["2","10"]'),
```

and I want to separate values in brackets like this

```
(1, 'Apple', '5', '8'),
...
(22, 'Mango', '5', '8'),
(23, 'Orange', '5', '8'),
(24, 'Banana', '2', '0'),
(25, 'Milk', '2', "0'),
...
(749, 'Bread', '2','10'),
```

Using Notepad++ "replace with" function.  I am open also to another solutions.

Thank you

Comment: replacing in 3 ways, but is too slow ... large amount of data

Comment: @ing.MichalHudak how long does it take? how can a notepad++-replacement be time-critical?

Comment: 2 reasons: 1. slow machine, 2. txt file have 23GB

Comment: I doubt Notepad++ is optimised for speed, what with the GUI. Try writing a short script that does the replacement and running it off the command line if you're worried about efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex replace all instances of:

```
'\["(.*?)","(.*?)"\]'
```

With:

```
'\1','\2'
```

Comment: @ing.MichalHudak Yeah the difference is ultimately going to be minor though. Unless you have gargantuan amounts of data, in which case you shouldn't be using Notepad++ anyway.

Comment: You are right. This computer don't have any IDE, or editor. Using what I have in moment. Don't have even admin privileges.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't even require regex. Use normal replacement mode. Then you have three passes:

```
Find what:    ["
Replace with: (empty string)
Find what:    "]
Replace with: (empty string)
Find what:    "
Replace with: '
```

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but too slow ... large amount of data